# Why do I get a runtime error saying syntax error in my sql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
desc = "Fishing Hooks";
code = "FH";
size = "#2";
cost = 2;
qnty = Integer.parseInt(hook2amount.getText());
amnt = qnty * cost;
Products h2 = new Products(desc,code,size,cost,qnty,amnt);
list.add(h2);
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
    pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into purchase(username,code,desc,size,cost,quantity,date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    pst.setString(1, user);
    pst.setString(2, code);
    pst.setString(3,desc);
    pst.setString(4,size);
    pst.setString(5, String.valueOf(cost));
    pst.setString(6, String.valueOf(qnty));
    pst.setString(7, date);
    pst.executeUpdate();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error " + e);
}
```

I'm getting a syntax error saying

> Error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,size,cost,quantity,date) values('sam','FH','Fishing Hooks','#2','2','2','7/' at line 1

I cant find my error

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a reserved keyword in MariaDB, put some backticks around it and it should work.

Comment: by solving that error i got another error saying   Error com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '7/28/2018' for column 'date' at row 1

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement itself is

```
insert into purchase(username,code,desc,size,cost,quantity,date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Notice that `desc` is a reserved keyword.

You need to escape it or change its name. It is good practice to escape all column names anyway, so change the insert statement to:

```
insert into purchase(`username`,`code`,`desc`,`size`,`cost`,`quantity`,`date`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

You should also set the parameters with the methods that correspond with their data types. Instead of `setString` everywhere, use `setInt` for the integer values `cost` and `qnty`, given your code.